Concerning the laws of ethics
If I'm think I'm about to be involved in a lawsuit and contacted lawyer A and found there is no conflict of interest at the initial time of consultation with my opposing party Bob and disclosed my side of the story to lawyer A, but later lawyer A was also consulted by Bob. Then, in this case, does lawyer A need to check conflict of interest first before providing consultation to Bob?
If yes, what happens next?
If no, then if later lawyer A found out that I'm the opposing party to Bob, then is it legal that lawyer A used the information I disclosed at initial consultation against me if lawyer A is later hired by Bob? What about vice versa? Thanks.
